# Adding a point in 3D graph

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, point

I have data as shown below and have no idea why the point (25,25,0) does not plotted into the graph.

```
X = [0,71,142,213,284,355,426;0,71,142,213,284,355,426;0,71,142,213,284,355,426;0,71,142,213,284,355,426;0,71,142,213,284,355,426;0,71,142,213,284,355,426];

Y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0;71,71,71,71,71,71,71;142,142,142,142,142,142,142;213,213,213,213,213,213,213;284,284,284,284,284,284,284;355,355,355,355,355,355,355];

IntensityError =

   1.0e-04 *

    0.4609    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.4609
    0.9217    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.9217
         0    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000

mesh(X,Y,Error)
hold on plot3(25,25,0,'*')
```

When you run the above code, you will see that the point (25,25,0) is not plotted.
I have tried to solve this problem for many days. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but the point shows on the figure in my quick test:

```
X = [0,71,142,213,284,355,426;
    0,71,142,213,284,355,426;
    0,71,142,213,284,355,426;
    0,71,142,213,284,355,426;
    0,71,142,213,284,355,426;
    0,71,142,213,284,355,426];

Y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
    71,71,71,71,71,71,71;
    142,142,142,142,142,142,142;
    213,213,213,213,213,213,213;
    284,284,284,284,284,284,284;
    355,355,355,355,355,355,355];

IntensityError = 1.0e-04 *[
    0.4609    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.4609;
    0.9217    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.9217;
         0    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0;
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000;
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000;
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000];



    figure;
    mesh(X,Y,IntensityError), hold on; 
    plot3(25,25,0,'*');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Martin!! I can do it!!